# The spinner is hidden by the background of the liner layout

Tags: android-layout

I want to display the spinner in a rectangle with soild fill color around it. My code is given below

```
          <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="113dp"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="9dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="9dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="9dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="9dp"
    android:background="@drawable/rectangle_shape"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:visibility="visible"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinmain"
        android:layout_width="352dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="416dp"
        android:dropDownVerticalOffset="35dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/view7" />
</LinearLayout>
```

and rectangle_shape.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/re/android">
 <item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="#FF0000" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item android:left="5dp" android:right="5dp"  android:top="5dp" >
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="#000000" />
    </shape>
   </item>
   </layer-list>
```

But the problem is that the spinner is hidden by the rectangle linear layout
How can I bring the spinner in front of it.Please suggest

Answer (score 0):

Try to change `android:layout_height="113dp"` from 113 to match_parent